# php mysql - search field and category if not null

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, full-text-search

I have a simple php mysql search that searches a database, however, i cannot seem to get it to search the text from the search field and the category, but i only want it to search the category if selected,

this is my code that i have tried:

```
if ($search !== null){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY price ".$price." LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit;

    $q   = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
    // Bind the params to the placeholders
    $q->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();
}


if ($search !== null && $category !== null){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) and category=:category ORDER BY price ".$price." LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit;

    $q   = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
    // Bind the params to the placeholders
    $q->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();
}
```

however, this still ignores the category field option if selected! any ideas?

they are being set as follows:

```
   // Check and set category
$category = (!empty($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : null);

// Check and set search
if(!empty($_GET['search'])){
    $search = $_GET['search'];
}else{
    $search = null;
}
```

Comment: How are $search and $category being set? Have you tested to make sure the second if statement is being executed?

Comment: @Shredder thankyou for your reply, i have added to the question to show how they are being set, and how would i check to see if it was being executed?

Comment: You can put an echo/die statement at the beginning of the `if` block. Put some code there that does something to let you know that block is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some debugging to make sure `$search` and `$category` are being set. That is most likely your problem. From the looks of it, `$category` should be getting set (since you said its coming from query string), but just check both to be sure. Something like:

```
if($category !== null)
    die("category = $category");
else {
    die("no category");
}
//do same test for $search
```

If users are accessing this page from a link (`<a href="search.php?category=Books">Books?</a>`), I don't see how `$_GET['search']` would be set.

I would suggest you change your `if` statements to be more efficient (only 1 should get executed):

```
if ($search !== null){
    if($category !== null){
        //query with category
    }
    else {
        //query w/o category
    }
}
```

Also, I would use `isset()` to check if these variables are instantiated instead of `empty()`.

Comment: thankyou, but for my form is using method="get", i would like it come from the query string in the url as i have other links as categories, which e.g. <a href="search.php?category=Books">Books?</a>

Comment: yeah found it was an issue with my IF statements, its working but i have got them all separately at the moment, will now merge them in to one, thankyou so much!!!